# How can I specify all metrics I need when compiling a model?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, precision-recall

I have the following line of code on my model

```py
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Which works perfectly and shows the accuracy after each epoch.

Now, my problem arises when I want other metrics to be shown too, like precision, recall or f1.

I don't know how can I do this?

For example, trying to add precision, I've tried this:

```py
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=[metrics.Accuracy(), metrics.Precision()])
```

and this:

```py
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy', 'precision'])
```

but none work, only 'accuracy' and 'AUC'.

Comment: Hi @Adria de Juan, Did you try with 'mse', 'rmse' metrics as you have used loss='mean_squared_error'? Please provide minimal reproducible code to replicate the issue. What dataset are you using? is it a regression model or classification model?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use different metrics for different outputs.

However they need to be passed as a dictionary as given in this [doc](https://keras.io/api/models/model/);

It is expressed as :

```
model.compile(
   optimizer='adam',
   loss={'output_1': 'loss_1', 'output_2': 'loss_2'},
   loss_weights={'output_1': 1., 'output_2': 0.2},
   metrics={'output_1': 'metric_1', 'output_2': ['metric_2', 'metric_3']})
```

Hence your code should be written as :

```
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics={output1: 'accuracy', output1 : 'precision'})
```